# Video not playing in Facebook News Feed

Tags: facebook, video

**UPDATE:** It turns out the page shouldn't have both the "og:video" and "og:video:url" tags. I removed one of them and everything worked as it should.

### Problem Statement

I have a page with OpenGraph tags to allow play a video in the Facebook News feed. Sharing the URL to Facebook appears to work, but the video does not properly play.

### OpenGraph Tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Jamie McMurray Ready to Defend Rolex 24 Title">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://media.weei.com/theme/9084/a/112508981/jamie-mcmurray-ready-to-defend-rolex-24-title.htm">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://media.weei.com/hosting/media/weei/1640379/mrn-autoracingpodcast-300x300.png">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="WEEI">
<meta property="og:description" content="He and his Chip Ganassi teammates are back together one year removed from winning a watch in the Rolex 24.">
<meta property="og:video" content="https://dih1l34ei3029.cloudfront.net/56275703/audiogram.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://dih1l34ei3029.cloudfront.net/56275703/audiogram.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://dih1l34ei3029.cloudfront.net/56275703/audiogram.mp4">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="300">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300">
```

According to the Facebook Debugger, FB is picking up the necessary tags.

### Outcome

When I attempt to embed the page in Facebook, it looks like it's *trying* to play the video.

[image]

But when I click the Play icon, it doesn't work.

[image]

I haven't been able to find any guidance online as to why these videos aren't playing. I've double checked the tags, inspected the video codecs... everything looks like it **should** be working.

But it's not.

Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are using flv format in your url and marking the content as video/mp4 . That wont work , make sure to use the right format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the page shouldn't have both the "og:video" and "og:video:url" tags. I removed one of them and everything worked as it should.